# Axios post request not working React Nodejs Mongodb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to post a data to the mongoose database but I keep getting Axios error 404. I need help. Is there something wrong in my code?

This is my modal, it contains the front end of the website

**AddForm.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios, { Axios } from "axios";

const AddForm = () =>{

    const [appData, setAppData] = useState({
        pName:"",
        appNum:"",
        datetime:"",
    })

const submit =(e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post("/addAppDetails", {
        pName: appData.pName, 
        appNum: appData.appNum, 
        datetime: appData.datetime, 
    })
    .then(res =>{
        console.log(res.appData)
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error);
      });
}


const handle = (e) => {
    const newData={...appData}
    newData[e.target.id] = e.target.value
    setAppData(newData)
    console.log(newData)
}

    return(
        <Form onSubmit={(e) => submit(e)}>
            <Form.Group>
                <Form.Control
                id="pName"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Patient Name"
                onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
                value={appData.pName}
                required/>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group>
                <Form.Control
                id="appNum"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Appointment Number"
                onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
                required/>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group>
                <Form.Control
                id="datetime"
                as="textarea"
                placeholder="Date and Time"
                onChange={(e) => handle(e)}
                required/>
            </Form.Group>

            <Button variant="success" type="submit" block>Update Appointment</Button>
        </Form>
    )
}

export default AddForm;
```

This is my backend, it contains the route/api for functionality

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

app.use(express.json()); //prints body request
app.use(cors());

const JWT_SECRET = "sdaikdhjiIHDiu8987J(@?!dDSF8645DAsadA[]ds54aASD()21asd1SFP";
const mongooseURL =
  "mongodb+srv://client:lolpassword@cluster0.lfrgaha.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

//server
app.listen(5001, () => {
  console.log("Server started successfully.");
});

//connect with DB
mongoose
  .connect(mongooseURL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to database successfully");
  })
  .catch((e) => console.log(e));

require("./models/appointmentDetails");
const AppDetails = mongoose.model("AppointmentDetails");

//add data to db
app.post("/addAppDetails", async(req, res) => {

  const newAppDetails = new AppDetails(req.body);

  try{
      newAppDetails.save();
      res.send(newAppDetails);
  }
  catch(err){
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
```

This is my database model.

**appointmentDetails.js**

```
const AppDetails = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        pName: String,
        appNum: String,
        datetime: String,
        status: String,
        action: String,
    },
    {
        collection: "AppointmentDetails",
    }
);

mongoose.model("AppointmentDetails", AppDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

404 means the url (including http://host:port) that you are using to send request & expecting response from, doesn't exist in your case.

While sending request, check if your node server is receiving the response or not, using logs, or a global middleware function logging every request info. This way you'll see whether the server is receiving the request or not, and thus find the problem.

As suggested in the [answer by @thillon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74154104/10624674) (now deleted probably), most likely in your case the url is incomplete (doesn't contain the server's host:port part), so you can follow their way to ensure that your request url is proper and thus make sure that your server is able to receive request is this particular case.

*Global middleware function*

Write this right after your `app.use(express.json())` statement.

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    // or log anything helpful in the req object
    next();
})
```